# Inject multi-line JS in Tritium

Tags: javascript, xpath, moovweb, tritium

I have a javascript snippet that I need to inject on each page to fire off my google analytics. I tried using inject and keep getting errors:

```
inject("// load ga.js if it doesn't exist
    if (!window._gat) {
        var ga = document.createElement("script"); ga.type = "text/javascript"; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    };")
```

What is the best way to approach this problem with tritium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inject()` function seems to convert the string to HTML and then place it into the current node. Since your string is JS, not valid HTML, all sorts of errors are thrown.

Instead, you can use Tritium's `insert_javascript()` function, described in the docs at: http://tritium.io/current#XMLNode.insert_javascript(Text%20%25js).

`insert_javascript()` also encloses the string in [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) tags so you don't have to worry about HTML character encodings and such.

Here's an example of how it could work in your case: http://tester.tritium.io/7532c4e18619051c5736a0ad990e4a33b1b3f00f

Comment: You can use `inject()` if your input is a string with valid HTML. For example, if you received a snippet like `<script type="text/javascript"> // some JS here </script>`, it would work.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I also had "s in there that I needed to escape.